# Why am I able to move opened files in OSX but not Windows?

Tags: operating-system

If I have a file (i.e. document, video) open in OSX, I can still move the file from folder to different folder, but in Windows it is not allowed. Why is this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it s not a question about programming as defined in the [help]

Comment: My apologies, could not find an approriate stack exchange site to ask. I felt it was important to programming so that I'll know how file i/o works with different operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows if you have kept open particular file it'll be locked until it finished the job or you closing it. Once the temp memory is released or unlocked you can move it.

Alternatively we have [unlock-er](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) software to override this task.

But in OSX, the memory mode is open and you can move it while doing another task. Its works like a rooted phone. I hope this helps.